# foundation watch doesn't work

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm running the foundation for emails,

when I run the foundation watch command, everything seems ok, I open the localhost:3000 and there is my template, but when I edit the html or sass files, the page doesn't reload or update the content, even if I force the reload, the page keeps same.

I attached a screenshot of terminal running command.

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDB9t.png)

Answer (score 1):

Are you editing the right file ? 
I had the same issue, the thing is that I was trying to edit index.html which was located in dist, while you have to edit the one that is in src/pages/

Hope this help